# Google Sign-In SDK Disconnect from an account

Tags: ios, swift, google-signin, googlesigninaccount

I am using Google Sign-In iOS SDK to implement the sign-in with Google feature. However, I am confused with the disconnect function.

`GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.disconnect()`

According to the documentation, it disconnects the current user from the app and revokes previous authentication. If the operation succeeds, the OAuth 2.0 token is also removed from keychain.

However, when I disconnect the Google Account in my app, I can still use the old id_token to fetch the user's data with the following API:

`https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?id_token=xxxxxx`

I can only see the `id_token` will be expired according to the `exp` field which is 3600s since the token is created.

What does the `disconnect()` actually mean? Why can the user's profile be fetched even the Google Account has been disconnected successfully?

Comment: `GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.disconnect()` isn't the same as `GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.signOut()`

Comment: @ElTomato, yes, they are not the same. However, why can I still use the old `id_token` to retrieve the user's profile even the user disconnects the app at the Google user console? 

The id_token will only be expired after 3600s. That means the server can still retrieve the updated user's name and profile image an hour after he disconnects.

Comment: You are able to use the token because you are still logged in.

Comment: I have called the `GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.signOut()` but I can still use the old `id_token` to get the user's information.